# Fetch a column value depending on a row number

Tags: r

I have the following df

```
Case Points
A    2
B    3
C    8
```

I would the like to fetch the Points of a certain row. So lets say I have a list with rownumbers 2 and 3

```
 rownumbers <- c(2,3)
```

Then I would like to the fetch the numbers 3 and 8. Could anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: `mydata[rownumbers,"Points"]`

Comment: You'll get to this in 3.4 of the manual: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing

Comment: you should check out basic R stuff, like data.frames and indexing

Comment: These are very basic R-skills. You will benefit a lot if you do some basic tutorials (also taking some of your other questions into account, in which you also have difficulties in very basic R operations).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be too simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mydata[rownumbers,"Points"]
```

This answered in comments so I made it as *community wiki*